# Using different build path for Unit Testing In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jar

I'm doing Java development in eclipse and using JUnit.  My application uses an old version of a library because of platform restrictions.  Is there any way I can run my unit tests with a new version of the library?  How do you configure a different build path for unit testing?

To clarify for everyone below:

Here is the problem.  Our platform requires a really old version of the java Servlet library.  But we want to use ServletUnit (a library for testing servlets in a unit testing framework).  This library will only work with newer versions for the java servlet lib.  I don't care that we test with a different version of the servlet library, it outweighs the negative.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by having your unit tests in a different project, so the projects will have different build paths.

The better question is WHY you want to do this. It's a bad idea to run your tests against something other than the production code. Why not either update the library in the application, or use the old library for the tests?

In response to your edit:

If you don't care about testing with the same libraries you use in production, then you don't care about code quality or correctness. There's no point in answering this because no answer will be a good fix to your problem. Your time would be better spent upgrading your platform to use the newest version of servlets.

Comment: Please see above for clarification.

Comment: And I would rather not have a separate project.  Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Comment: You cannot have multiple build paths for different parts of the same project. One build path per project.

Comment: As far as i know, @KonstantinKomissarchik is right. One project, one build path. This is incredibly annoying at times, particularly around unit tests, but it's how Eclipse rolls.

Comment: In response to the edit in the answer above:  That is pretty presumptuous of you to say I "don't care about code quality or correctness".  I didn't ask for your opinion, I was asking help in solving a specific problem.  Upgrading the platform is not possible. Why are you telling me that is if you know nothing about the project??  Sometimes in the real world you have to deal with restrictions that are beyond your control.  It's called engineering...

Comment: Your original question has been answered: You can only do different build paths if you put your tests in a different project. You've rejected this, so there's nothing else we can do. As for the rest, if you think it's OK to test with something other than the same stuff in production, there's not much we can do to help you. Sometimes engineering means biting the bullet and upgrading (which can entail a change in requirements; those happen all the tie), or writing your tests with the old version of servlets. Your test suite will be worthless otherwise.